# How to use auto keyword in argument list in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, auto

How to replace auto keyword from the function parameter when there will be multiple type arguments called with this function? because I want to use `-std=c++11` and I am getting this error in omnet++:

```
**error: use of auto in parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14**
```

```
void get_index(auto s_arra[], auto elem) {
    ...
}

void main() {
    get_index(float array1, float var1);
    get_index(int array2, int var2);
}
```

Comment: You switch to using a template like you would have done before C++20.

Comment: `auto` in function declaration is C++20, not C++14. generic lambda are C++14 though. gcc error message is misleading here.

Comment: Since you pass `float` arrays and values, use `float` instead of `auto`? Or if you want the function to be more generic then perhaps templates?

Comment: Make it a template

Comment: Your code in `main` is not valid.

Comment: @interjay thank you for your reply, why my code in main is not valid?

Comment: You can't put a type name like `float` before a function argument.

Comment: @interjay yes, you are right, it is just for question that two different data type of argument is there for calling function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void get_index(auto s_arra[], auto elem) {
    //...
}
```

Would be valid only in C++20 (gcc error message is misleading)

previously, you use template the verbose way

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void get_index(T1 s_arra[], T2 elem) {
    //...
}
```

and probably they use same type, so

```
template <typename T>
void get_index(T s_arra[], T elem) {
    //...
}
```